# How to find the initial rate of a rate plot?

Tags: kinetics

[image]

In the graph above, how do I find the initial rate of $$\frac{d[A]}{dt}$$

My balanced chemical equation is $$\ce{3A + B -> 2C}\\[1em]$$

Comment: Just draw a straight line that overlays the first few points of the purple curve. (It doesn't have to be super accurate. Or at least, if you wanted something that was super accurate, you probably shouldn't be doing it graphically.)

Comment: Can you expand on that? I watched a video and they said to draw a tangent line through zero, and to pick two points on the tangent. Once I find the slope of those points, do I multiply it by -1/3?

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned drawing a straight line for the purple curve? I thought I was supposed to draw a line for the blue curve since we're finding the initial rate of [A]?

Comment: The slope of the blue line will give you the initial rate of change of the concentration of A. If you want the initial rate of the reaction, you do have to multiply by -1/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most accurate results, simply draw a line from the first two point of the graph and find its slope. This can also be done numerically. Say the first two observations are $[A]_{t_0}$ and $[A]_{t_1}$ at times $t_0$ and $t_1$, respectively:

$$
\left(\dfrac{d[A]}{dt}\right)_{t_{0}} \approx \dfrac{[A]_{t_1}-[A]_{t_0}}{t_1 - t_0}
$$

**Note:** we are approximating the *initial* rate at $t_0$ with the *average* rate between $t_0$ and $t_1$. The initial rate will be slightly more negative than the average rate we have calculated.

Comment: Reference: [ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/02%3A_Reaction_Rates/2.05%3A_Reaction_Rate)